# Reading from tf.train.string_input_producer

Tags: tensorflow

I have a dataset with about 1.6 million images. I have stored the full path to these images in a text file (each full path in one line, thus with 1.6 million lines).
I have stored this list in a `FIFOQueue` using the `tf.train.string_input_producer` function. I would like to read the name of a file from this, and then read it in a function and then perform some preprocessing on it before feeding it for training.

A small snippet from my code file is the following :

```
imgnames = []    
for line in open(imgfilelist, 'r'):
   imgnames.append(line.strip())
imgnames = tf.convert_to_tensor(imgnames)
input_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(imgnames, num_epochs=50,\
                                             capacity=500)
# Not using TextLineReader() since I do not have a CSV file.
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(input_queue)
```

This gives the key as follows :

```
 <tf.Tensor 'ReaderRead_1:0' shape=() dtype=string>
```

and the value as follows :

```
  <tf.Tensor 'ReaderRead_1:1' shape=() dtype=string>
```

At this point I feel lost.

1. Why `shape=()` ?
2. How do I obtain the actual filename which I can use inside a function ?

Comment: it's a node in computation graph, you have to use `session.run` to get actual value

Comment: Okay. So, other than that WholeFileReader is a correct thing to do and in order to get the filename i would need to use pop() method ?

Comment: I don't think you want to use `WholeFileReader` — it will return a single string containing all of the file names. `TextLineReader` reads a file delimited by newlines: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/readers#TextLineReader ; it is not specific to CSV files.

Comment: yes. thank you. i figured that out later by reading the source code. :) thanks a lot again.